# All possible combinations of ways to write an equation

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics

I want to define a function in Mathematica where I get all combinations of an expression, e.g., input:

```
{q,p1,p2}
```

Output:

```
{q + p1 + p2, q + p1 - p2, q - p1 + p2, -q + p1 + p2, -q - p1 + p2, -q + p1 - p2, -q - p1 - p2}
```

I am only interested in Plus/Minus.

I really need your help guys.

Answer (score 14):

`Tuples` + `Dot`:

```
Tuples[{1, -1}, 3].{q, p1, p2}
```

> {p1 + p2 + q, p1 - p2 + q, -p1 + p2 + q, -p1 - p2 + q, p1 + p2 - q, 
>    p1 - p2 - q, -p1 + p2 - q, -p1 - p2 - q}

For arbitrary number of variables:

```
ClearAll[f]
f[n_] := Tuples[{1, -1}, n].Array[Subscript[q, #] &, n]

f[3] // TeXForm
```

> $\scriptsize\left\{q_1+q_2+q_3,q_1+q_2-q_3,q_1-q_2+q_3,q_1-q_2-q_3,-q_1+q_2+q_3,-q_1+q_2-q_3,-q_1-q_2+q_3,-q_1-q_2-q_3\right\}$

Also

```
Flatten @ Outer[{q, p1, p2}.{##} &, {1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, -1}]
```

> {p1 + p2 + q, p1 - p2 + q, -p1 + p2 + q, -p1 - p2 + q, p1 + p2 - q, 
>    p1 - p2 - q, -p1 + p2 - q, -p1 - p2 - q}

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you give me an example of how to extend it for q,p1,p2,..pn

Comment: @user69814, i added a generalization for n variables.

Comment: You are the best. Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 12):

```
{q, p1, p2}*# & /@ Tuples[{+1, -1}, 3]
```

> {{q, p1, p2}, {q, p1, -p2}, {q, -p1, p2}, {q, -p1, -p2}, {-q, p1, 
>     p2}, {-q, p1, -p2}, {-q, -p1, p2}, {-q, -p1, -p2}}